# How to call timestamps using alexa

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I have date showing me machine temperatures kept in time stamps with data and time, id like to call these timestamps from my dynamodb table and have alexa read my answer, is this possible or would i need to seperate time and date and keep them as ISO 8601 format

Comment: Just format the timestamps into date and time before alexa is reading it. 
 [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) can help you.

Comment: @MaiKay my data comes out in the following format '21/02/2017 
07:38:17', is there anyway for alexa to be able to read this as its not in ISO 8601?

Comment: As i said moment.js can help you to format the date in the desired format (ISO8601): `moment(date, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").toISOString();`

Comment: @MaiKay okay thanks, so if i were to call a date and time with alexa, it should match with the corresponding time stamp?